# How to get default result when query fetch no results

Tags: solr

I want to display some default results when query fails to fetch results. As of now when I use some junk value for querying it leads to no results but as per my requirement need to display some 10 default results based on some conditions.

Comment: Make a new query if the first query returns zero results - that way you can tune the second query in any way you find useful, instead of having to try to have duplicate sets of what relates to what in your previous query (i.e. facets, etc.)? Also be aware that this _can_ be confusing for users (but might not be), depending on what and how you're displaying the information.

Comment: yes agree with @matsLindh...if there is no matching data...it should ideally mention that no records found

Comment: @MatsLindh  Abhijit Bashetti  Yeah I do agree with you but I have the requirement to display some custom results. As of now, I am using two ajax call, one for the first time if I get no results I am doing another but is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: That depends what you're querying. There's nothing saying your controller can't make two parallel queries to Solr (and if the general fallback query is common across users, it can just be cached in your application instead), but the gist is: make two queries. It's what's going to happen internally anyway.